# No repos found in rhel 8 after installation

Tags: rhel, package-management, repository, application

After installing rhel 8 it says I do not have any repos. What do I do as I am unable to install any applications? I tried using the subscription-manager as well to connect to the repository but still didn't work.

Comment: Is the system registered with Red Hat?

Comment: System is not registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is not registered. Until that is done, the Red Hat repos won't be available. You can add other repos like EPEL but most packages including kernel releases, applications like Apache, Nginx, Java/JDK, and other system software will require the Red Hat repos to be available and even packages in other repos like EPEL, etc will have dependencies that are only available in the Red Hat repos. If you don't want to pay for an enterprise subscription, you can get a developer subscription for free by joining the developer program although it won't include support.

Unless you have a specific need for RHEL itself, you can also use Rocky Linux or Alma Linux which don't require subscriptions, have their repos available from the start, and are 100% binary compatible with RHEL. They are basically the free version of Red Hat much like CentOS was and will function in virtually the exact same way when it comes to running software, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I actually use Centos 8 so I'll probably stick to that.

Comment: @kwinful You are welcome. CentOS 8 is actually EOL so you are better off using Rocky Linux or Alma Linux. If my answer has resolved your question, then you can accept it by clicking the check mark.